# erro in SDK dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When running the flutter build apk command, I am getting the following error:

Pubspec.yaml
[image]

Error code:
[image]

Comment: upgrade your flutter

Comment: Go to your pubspec.yaml and change the sdk version under enviroment

Comment: Please post pubspec.yaml here

Answer (score 2):

Open your `pubspec.yaml`

search for this:

[image: Pubspec]

Then change the SDK to: `">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"`

Comment: My code in Pubspec.yaml is already like this, but it didn't work

Comment: After updating the pubspec.yaml is it still not working? does he give the same error? @Álefe

Comment: gives exactly the same error

Comment: Could you show me your pubspec.yaml code. (you can edit your post en copy paste it in there) @Álefe

Answer (score 1):

You can write

`flutter upgrade`

command in terminal to update flutter sdk